# Avast on OSX: How to add hidden files and folders as an exception?

Tags: macos, anti-virus, avast, metasploit

I've installed avast from `brew cask`

I'm trying to add `/usr/local/share/metasploit-framework` folder as an exception for a file system shield.
Even though I have "show hidden files" option enabled on my mac, Avast is still not showing hidden files (such as `/usr/...`)

Hidden files in Finder:
[image]

avast GUI - no hidden files:
[image]

How to add the exception if there is no obvious way to make Avast see hidden files? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file selector dialog seems to not be affected by the setting to show hidden files, but you can specify a manual path to hidden folders using the Go... command. Within the selector modal, press ⌘ + ⇧ + G to access the function. From there, you can specify a path manually, even a hidden one.

[image: go-dialog]

Keep in mind that this only allows access to hidden folders. Hidden files are still invisible.

Comment: I've already solved this problem using `$ sudo chflags nohidden /usr` and then `$ sudo chflags hidden /usr`... But this is way more elegant solution!!! Great answer!